# SearchView doesn't fill the entire width

Tags: android, layout, menu, searchview

I'm adding SearchView to my Toolbar by menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="@android:string/search_go"
        android:visible="true"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I don't know why but SearchView is moved to the right:
[image]

Any ideas why is that happening?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, try to add this programmatically:

```
searchView.setMaxWidth( Integer.MAX_VALUE );
```

If this doesn't work try to replace the `<item>` tag to `<SearchView>`

**If using API 20 and above do this**
Add this to your `styles.xml` file:

```
/*Theme name and parent can be different - depends on the one that already 
declared in you manifest under the tag <application> theme:AppTheme*/
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> /
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="android:maxWidth">@dimen/maxSize</item>
</style>
<dimen name="maxSize">1000dp</dimen>
```

Comment: I used searchView.setMaxWidth( Integer.MAX_VALUE ); and used <SearchView> instead of menu with <item> and nothig works.

Comment: @DawidHyży try this

Comment: Because of lack of time I've unfortunately ended with RelativeLayout with EditText and ImageButton to mimic SearchView. I will try this next time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but in my case, it happened that I had a menu drawer icon image in the toolbar (in the layout file) and at the same time had enabled the home button programmatically like so

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Setting this as false (or removing this code) freed up space for the drawer icon and the SearchView. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)

    // Make SearchView fill screen width
    ((menu?.findItem(R.id.action_bar_search)?.actionView) as SearchView).apply {
        maxWidth = 1999
    }
    
    return true
}
```

1. `action_bar_search` is the name of the item id in the menu xml
2. The max width needs to be higher than 1000 for it to fill the view.
   While the docs do not specify how to do this, they have an example that shows how to access the maxWidth method.

https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup#create-sc

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE) works but other items of the menu are not showing.

In this page https://material.io/components/app-bars-top#specs says that padding of the toolbar is 16dp and the size of the item and space is 24dp.

So, I saved those dimensions

```
<dimen name="app_bar_padding">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="app_bar_size_menu_item">24dp</dimen>
```

After, I setMaxWidth in order to calculate a better width for the search (pixels)

```
// appBarWidth - 2 * margin app - menu item size
val appBarPadding = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.app_bar_padding)
val menuItemSize = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.app_bar_size_menu_item)
searchView.maxWidth = binding.toolbar.width - 2 * appBarPadding - menuItemSize
```

That example was for only one item. If you has more items, please don't forget the **space** between items.

Result:

[image]